# Is $\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]}{\langle4,\sqrt{10}\rangle}$ a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

My answer is yes. I took the following route. Is it correct? $$\frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]}{\langle4,\sqrt{10}\rangle}= \frac{\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{10}]}{\langle2,\sqrt{10}\rangle}= \frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{\langle X^2-10\rangle}}{\langle2,\bar{X}\rangle}=\frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{X^2-10}}{\frac{\langle2,X,X^2-10\rangle}{X^2-10}}= \frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{\langle2,{X},X^2-10\rangle} = \frac{\frac{\mathbb{Z}[X]}{X}}{\langle2,\bar{X}^2-10\rangle}=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle2,10\rangle}=\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{\langle2\rangle}$$

Am I doing any wrong at any step? (Please assume I have tried using appropriate isomorphism theorems at appropriate steps.)

Comment: Looks good to me. Finally note that $\mathbb Z/\langle 2\rangle$ is indeed a field.

Comment: Why is $\langle 4,\sqrt{10}\rangle=\langle 2,\sqrt{10}\rangle$? (First step.)

Comment: @StinkingBishop Note that $2 = \sqrt{10}\cdot\sqrt{10} - 2\cdot 4$.

Comment: @Christoph, what if we have $5$ in place $4$. Isn't it going to be a field again?

Comment: @epsilon_delta Then $\gcd(10,5)=5$ so you end up with $\mathbb Z/\langle 5\rangle$, which is a field as well.

Comment: @Christoph But this question is from one of the nationwide exams, where the answer is given to be one of them is field and another is not.

Comment: Then either you cited the question wrong, looked up the wrong answer, or there is a mistake in the given answer!

Comment: More precisely, $<4,\sqrt{10}> $is not a maximal ideal.

Comment: Yes! you are correct. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general
$$
\frac{\mathbb Z[\sqrt d]}{\langle k, \sqrt{d}\rangle} \cong \frac{\mathbb Z [X]}{\langle k, X, X^2-d\rangle} \cong \mathbb Z/\langle\gcd(k,d)\rangle,
$$
which is a field if and only if $\gcd(k,d)$ is prime. That's the case for  $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]/\langle 4,\sqrt{10}\rangle$ with $\gcd(4,10)=2$ as well as $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{10}]/\langle 5,\sqrt{10}\rangle$ with $\gcd(5,10)=5$.